# How to send free SMS from vb .net application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sms-gateway

I want to send free SMS from vb .net application through my way2sms account.  If it is possible, then please give me step by step instruction on how to accomplish that.

Comment: Contact your provider and ask if they have an API

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Try

    send("way2sms_userid", "way2sms_password", txtxmsg.Text, txtphn.Text)
    Response.Write("message send successfully......")
Catch
    Response.Write("Error Occured!!!")
End Try
End Sub

Public Sub send(uid As String, password As String, message As String, no As String)
Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx?uid=" & uid & "&pwd=" & password & "&msg=" & message & "&phone=" & no & "&provider=way2sms"), HttpWebRequest)
Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(myReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim respStreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream())
Dim responseString As String = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
respStreamReader.Close()
myResp.Close()
End Sub
```